# Vb.net File in use

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a VB.Net program running on vista that says a file is in use but the same program on XP does not have that error.

Comment: Impossible to answer from the information you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you wrap disposable resources in [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) statement to ensure they are properly released:

```
Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=c:\BAAW\Data\BAAW.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
Using cmd As conn.CreateCommand()
    conn.Open()
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Employees"
    Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While rdr.Read()
            Console.WriteLine(rdr(0))
        End While
    End Using
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, I'll do a rewrite and see if that fixes.  Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Download [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) - you can use that to determine which process has the file in question open.

Comment: Sorry, to expand, the program opens an sql connection then when I open a new mdf file I close() the old connection and open() the new connection.  This is fine.  When I try to open() the first connection I get a "file in use" error, but only when I use the vista machine, not when I use the XP machine??

Comment: @Brad Henderson, could you show your code of connecting to SQL?

Comment: Public conn As New SqlConnection
Public FileName As String = "c:\BAAW\Data\BAAW.mdf"
 Public connString As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=" & FileName & ";Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
conn.ConnectionString = connString
conn.Open()


and when I finish with it I do this:

conn.Dispose()
conn.Close()

Comment: Does Process Explorer show that the file is in use by another application?

Comment: Will A: I have Process Explorer running but can't find a reference to file usage??

Comment: Will A, if you are still out there, you were correct in that Process Explorer did tell me.  Except it wasn't my VB.NEt program that was holding the file but the sqlservr.exe that was holding it.  Do you know how to force sqlservr to release a file?